# GitHub profiles no longer show programming language statistics

Tags: github

I used to see beneath my GitHub profile (along with my current location and URL) a list of the languages I program in, based on what data was in my public repositories.

Did this recently disappear? And is there any way to get them back?

Comment: You might be interested in [Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/).

Answer (score 12):

It's been removed from all profiles. It must have happened around September 2013.

It doesn't look like it's coming back.

However, if you look at your profile and then view the source of the page you will see in the `description` meta tag that it is still there.

```
<meta name="description" content="pinkpanther has 58 repositories written in 
 Scala, Ruby, and SoftGlove. Follow their code on GitHub." />
```

Comment: Even that is gone now :(

Answer (score 3):

Doing a search for a user will present their most commonly-used languages (by number of repositories) on the left sidebar, eg. https://github.com/search?q=user%3Astuartpb. It's not exactly "getting [the feature] back", but it's close.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative third party https://starhub.be or https://starhub.be/YOUR-USER-NAME will display statics about the used programming language.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers here appear outdated and no longer show user programming language stats.

You can use "https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=YOUR-USER-NAME", replacing `YOUR-USER-NAME` with your actual user GitHub name.

However, this will only show you languages most commonly used in *public* repositories, not private commits.

More info found here: https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats